# C# List Проверить существование элемента

Tags: c#, list

Есть структура и список её объектов. Как проверить существование элемента с определенным индексом?

```
public static struct Coord
{
    int id;
    int x;
    int y;

    public Coord(int _id, int _x, int _y) :this()
    {               
        x = _x;
        y = _y;
    }
}

static List<Coord>  house=new List<Coord>();
```

Так низяяя!

```
if (house.Count>1 && house[id]!=null)
{

}
```

А как можно?

Comment: а так: `if(id>=0 && id<house.Count){ }`

Comment: house[id]!=null - что такое `id`? Номер порядковый номер записи или id из структуры?

Comment: номер записи, индекс искомого элемента

Comment: так-то структура не может быть null

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вы же понимаете, что `id` в общем случае не равен индексу элемента?

Если вам нужно проверить, что в списке есть элемент с определенным `id`, то можно воспользоваться методом расширения `Any` и сделать поля структуры публичными:

```
public static struct Coord
{
    public int id;
    ...
}

if (house.Any(_ => _.id == id)) { }
```

Если вам нужно узнать, существует ли элемент с определенным индексом, то можно проверить, что индекс входит в промежуток от 0 до количества элементов в списке (как в своем комментарии отметил @qzavyer):

```
if (id >= 0 && id < house.Count) { }
```